# How to reduce task size in Spark MLib?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to implement Random Forest Classifier using Apache Spark (2.2.0) and Java.

Basically I've followed [the example from the Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-classification-regression.html#random-forest-classifier)

For test purposes I'm using a local cluster:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                    .builder()
                    .master("local[*]")
                    .appName(appName)
                    .getOrCreate();
```

My training/test data includes 30k rows. Data is fetched from REST APIs and transformed to Spark DataSet.

```
List<PreparedWUMLogFile> logs = //... get from REST API
Dataset<PreparedWUMLogFile> dataSet = spark.createDataset(logs, Encoders.bean(PreparedWUMLogFile.class));
Dataset<Row> data = dataSet.toDF();
```

For many stages I get the following warning message:

> [warn] o.a.s.s.TaskSetManager - Stage 0 contains a task of very large size (3002 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.

How I can reduce the task size in this case?

**Edit:**

To be more concrete: There are 5 of 30 stages that produce these warning messages.

- rdd at StringIndexer.scala:111 (two times)
- take at VectorIndexer.scala:119
- rdd at VectorIndexer.scala:122
- rdd at Classifier.scala:82

Comment: This generally happens when data is not evenly distributed across partitions and there is skew in your data.Uneven distribution leads some of the partitions to create really huge results causing this issue. First thing I would try changing is the spark.sql.shuffle.partitions property.

You can do a coalesce or repartition your Dataset.

Comment: As @AkhilanandBenkalVenkanna said,the issue is that some partitions have more data than others, you could try to coalesce or repartition your Dataset,like dataset.repartition(num).toDF().

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I have tried different number of partitions (up to 30) but task sizes still remain the same. Increasing spark.sql.shuffle.partitions from 200 (default value) to 1000 didn't help too.